# 10MB Image Using 500MB RAM

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, vulkan

I'm having a memory issue in my Vulkan application. Loading a 10mb PNG image is using almost 500mb of ram.

```
TextureObject* createTextureImage(const char* File) {

    auto Tex = Textures.emplace_back(new TextureObject(_Driver));

    //decode
    unsigned error = lodepng::decode(Tex->Pixels, Tex->Width, Tex->Height, File);

    //if there's an error, display it
    if (error) printf("PNG Decoder error: (%i) %s", error, lodepng_error_text(error));

    Tex->Empty = false;

    VkDeviceSize imageSize = Tex->Width * Tex->Height * 4;

    //
    //  Image Staging Buffer
    VkBufferCreateInfo stagingBufferInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO };
    stagingBufferInfo.size = imageSize;
    stagingBufferInfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT;

    VmaAllocationCreateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.usage = VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_CPU_ONLY;
    allocInfo.flags = VMA_ALLOCATION_CREATE_MAPPED_BIT;

    VkBuffer stagingImageBuffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    VmaAllocation stagingImageBufferAlloc = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    vmaCreateBuffer(_Driver->allocator, &stagingBufferInfo, &allocInfo, &stagingImageBuffer, &stagingImageBufferAlloc, nullptr);

    memcpy(stagingImageBufferAlloc->GetMappedData(), Tex->Pixels.data(), static_cast<size_t>(imageSize));
    Tex->Pixels.clear();

    VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO };
    imageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    imageInfo.extent.width = static_cast<uint32_t>(Tex->Width);
    imageInfo.extent.height = static_cast<uint32_t>(Tex->Height);
    imageInfo.extent.depth = 1;
    imageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
    imageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
    imageInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB;
    imageInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    imageInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    imageInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
    imageInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    imageInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;

    allocInfo.usage = VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_GPU_ONLY;

    VmaAllocationInfo imageBufferAllocInfo = {};
    vmaCreateImage(_Driver->allocator, &imageInfo, &allocInfo, &Tex->Image, &Tex->Allocation, nullptr);
    //
    //  CPU->GPU Copy
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = _Driver->_SceneGraph->beginSingleTimeCommands();
    VkImageMemoryBarrier imgMemBarrier = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER };
    imgMemBarrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    imgMemBarrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    imgMemBarrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    imgMemBarrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    imgMemBarrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    imgMemBarrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    imgMemBarrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    imgMemBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    imgMemBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
    imgMemBarrier.image = Tex->Image;
    imgMemBarrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    imgMemBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
        commandBuffer,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
        0,
        0, nullptr,
        0, nullptr,
        1, &imgMemBarrier);

    VkBufferImageCopy region = {};
    region.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    region.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    region.imageExtent.width = static_cast<uint32_t>(Tex->Width);
    region.imageExtent.height = static_cast<uint32_t>(Tex->Height);
    region.imageExtent.depth = 1;

    vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(commandBuffer, stagingImageBuffer, Tex->Image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region);

    imgMemBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
    imgMemBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    imgMemBarrier.image = Tex->Image;
    imgMemBarrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
    imgMemBarrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
        commandBuffer,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
        0,
        0, nullptr,
        0, nullptr,
        1, &imgMemBarrier);

    _Driver->_SceneGraph->endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);

    vmaDestroyBuffer(_Driver->allocator, stagingImageBuffer, stagingImageBufferAlloc);

    VkImageViewCreateInfo textureImageViewInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO };
    textureImageViewInfo.image = Tex->Image;
    textureImageViewInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    textureImageViewInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB;
    textureImageViewInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    textureImageViewInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    textureImageViewInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    textureImageViewInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    textureImageViewInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
    vkCreateImageView(_Driver->device, &textureImageViewInfo, nullptr, &Tex->ImageView);

    VkSamplerCreateInfo samplerInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO };
    samplerInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.anisotropyEnable = VK_TRUE;
    samplerInfo.maxAnisotropy = 16;
    samplerInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_INT_OPAQUE_BLACK;
    samplerInfo.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS;
    samplerInfo.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    samplerInfo.minLod = 0.0f;
    samplerInfo.maxLod = 0.0f;
    if (vkCreateSampler(_Driver->device, &samplerInfo, nullptr, &Tex->Sampler) != VK_SUCCESS) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create texture sampler!");
#endif
    }

    return Tex;
}
```

I've narrowed the allocation down to happening in this function. Simply swapping the image being loaded from the 10mb png over to a 1kb png drastically reduces memory consumption during this function call.

Am I doing something wrong here causing massive amounts of memory to be allocated and not freed?

Placing breakpoints on every line shows the huge allocation occurs right after the call to:

`unsigned error = lodepng::decode(Tex->Pixels, Tex->Width, Tex->Height, File);`

How can loading a 10mb png file use upwards of 500mb to load?

`lodepng::decode` fills the following 3 variables inside `Tex`

```
unsigned int Width = 0;
unsigned int Height = 0;
std::vector<unsigned char> Pixels = {};
```

Even the 1kb png uses around 5mb to load which seems awfully high.

I have also tried using [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) to load the png files and it gave the same result.

EDIT2: The 10mb png is 4096x4096 and the 1kb png is 16x16.

EDIT2: After some memory profiling, 58,000 instances of void accounting for 563,000,000 bytes get are allocated after checking one of the memory spikes and over 500,000,000 of that is sitting inside the vector I called `.clear()` on. I'm not sure how to really deallocate this or if it's even that big of an issue?

Comment: Did you try to see now many RAM consumes any other program? I mean image viewer or something?

Comment: What are the actual dimensions of your image? That will ultimately define the size of the raw bitmap. EDIT: I just created a 10.000 x 10.000 PNG of solid white, which turned out to be 32kb, so PNG definitely performs a decent amount of compression.

Comment: I see `new TextureObject(_Driver)` but I don't see a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: The 10mb png is 4096x4096 and the 1kb png is 16x16. It looks like I need to figure out how to reduce memory usage on large images.

Comment: So it should only take around 64 MB. Are you sure this 500 MB is actually committed instead of simply allocated as virtual memory?

Comment: @goodvibration might be because they are stored in a vector and deleted later on?

Comment: I'm watching memory usage inside visual studio while my application is running and see it shoot up every time I load another instance of the image. Task manager shows my application to increase by about 64mb each time I load a new instance. Watching memory usage on the GPU from inside task manager shows a sizable increase in memory usage unfortunately I don't know how to get an exact value. After 4-5 instances visual studio shows over 2GB memory usage and it has me very worried that something is very wrong here.

Comment: @KKlouzal: "*VmaAllocationCreateInfo*" What is this type and how does it work? If we can't see the actual Vulkan memory allocation commands, we can't really help you.

Comment: `vma*` commands come from this library https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator I would usually create a simple test case showing my issue but that would require over 1000 lines of code just to display the issue. I believe I've narrowed everything down to this function call. I will provide any necessary code anyone thinks is relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: After some memory profiling, 58,000 instances of void accounting for 563,000,000 bytes get are allocated after checking one of the memory spikes and over 500,000,000 of that is sitting inside the vector I called `.clear()` on. I'm not sure how to really deallocate this or if it's even that big of an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can loading a 10mb png file use upwards of 500mb to load?

Well, its 10MB of compressed data. All of the buffers you are throwing around here are after decompression, so 64MB each ...

One possible leak is that `vector.clear()` isn't guaranteed to reallocate, so while you call `clear()` here to free the objects it's possible that you are still sitting on 64MB of backing storage which is not released until the vector is destroyed.

Comment: After some memory profiling, 58,000 instances of void accounting for 563,000,000 bytes get are allocated after checking one of the memory spikes and over 500,000,000 of that is sitting inside the vector I called `.clear()` on. I'm not sure how to really deallocate this or if it's even that big of an issue?

Comment: @KKlouzal: [shrink_to_fit()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit).

Comment: Other approach would be to store pointers (smart or otherwise) in the vector, and then the memory allocation isn't tied to the lifetime of the vector.